# I can't use the key Alt GR in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I can not use the '`@`' and '`~`' symbols because Ubuntu suddenly stopped recognizing my `Alt Gr` key

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I'm from Mexico so I tried to change the keyboard input but it doesn't work

My config:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs7RA.jpg

My laptop keyboard

https://i.stack.imgur.com/THDVU.jpg

What I can do ?